# Regex string occurence in last 60 minutes across a log file

Tags: python

I am trying to search a string occurrence in last 60 minutes in a log file.

for which I set two variable then try to find the string between those two from log file-

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now() ## 3/13/18 13:17:31
past_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=60) ## 3/13/18 12:17:31
```

As string (SESN0066E) occurred between two strings [declared datetime stamps]

```
  def format_time(t):
        s = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        formattedTime = s.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
        return formattedTime

    start_time=format_time((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)))
    current_time=format_time(datetime.datetime.now())

    with open('server.log') as my_log:
       a = [re.findall(r'\[('+str(start_time)+')\](.*?)\[('+str(current_time)+')\]+',line) for line in my_log.readlines() if 'SESN0066E:' in line]
    print a
```

Here my server log file is in below format -

```
[3/13/18 10:31:18:360 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
form" property is "true".
[3/13/18 13:17:31:615 CET] 00000078 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:633 CET] 00000082 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:635 CET] 00000082 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:707 CET] 000000a8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:709 CET] 000000a8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:856 CET] 0000007c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:800 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
form" property is "true"
[3/13/18 13:17:31:858 CET] 0000007c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:872 CET] 000000aa webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
```

here only once occurrence found between current_time (3/13/18 13:17:31) and past_time (3/13/18 12:17:31)-

**Expected Result:**

```
['[3/13/18 13:17:31:800 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
form" property is "true"']
```

**or**

```
[[3/13/18 13:17:31:800 CET]]
```

But I am getting Empty List, not sure what I am missing here. [Python 2.6], I can not install any other modules or upgrade.

Comment: You just want the timestamps for those lines that contain SESN0066E?

Comment: @Bill Bell, Yes, I need list of the time stamp only basically, but it would be good if output contains the line[exception].

Comment: You can probably use the answer from Rakesh then. Please ask him to change it slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet should help. You also need to add the micro-seconds to the `current_time & past_time`.

```
import re
import datetime

s = """[3/13/18 10:31:18:360 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
form" property is "true".
[3/13/18 13:17:31:615 CET] 00000078 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:633 CET] 00000082 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:635 CET] 00000082 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:707 CET] 000000a8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:709 CET] 000000a8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:856 CET] 0000007c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below.
[3/13/18 13:17:31:800 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
form" property is "true"
[3/13/18 13:17:31:858 CET] 0000007c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception:
[3/13/18 13:17:31:872 CET] 000000aa webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp reportRecursiveError Error Page Exception  The server cannot use the error page specified for your application because of the exception printed below."""

current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("3/13/18 13:17:31:800", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f' )
past_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("3/13/18 12:17:31:800", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f')

res = []
for i in s.split("\n"):
    if "SESN0066E" in i: 
        val =  i[i.find("[")+1:i.find("]")][:-3].strip() 
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(val, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f')

        if past_time <= t <= current_time:    #Check if log time is between past_time & current_time
            print i
            print val
```

**Output:**

```
[3/13/18 13:17:31:800 CET] 0000000a WXSProperties I   SESN0066E: The value of the "com.ibm.websphere.objectgrid.container.heartbeat.any
3/13/18 13:17:31:800
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for the response, and i can get what you suggested by `[re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]+',line)[0] for line in my_log.readlines() if 'SESN0066E:' in line]` but I want those occurrences if happened in specific timestamp (sorry for less/unclear info, let me update main question.

Comment: You can then look if start string is in line.

Comment: I am not sure what current_time is in the line

Comment: I just have added more info- in summary I am trying to fetch the STRING from a log if it occurred in last 60 minutes.

Comment: @RahulTrivedi. Updated snippet.

Comment: Awesome, works like charm- and I doubt if its going to impact on performance if there is 10GB of log to process! Thanks.